# LLDB showing "summary unavailable" for strings

Tags: c++, debugging, c++17, c++20, clion

So i had this error with a large code that im working on for college, i need to visualize how strings get reorder while debugging in order to know my program is working, but debugger just shows (stringVariableName) = Summary unavailable. I created this small piece of code to test with standalone strings, vector and integers to see if it made a difference, but it only shows integers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> testString = {"test1", "test2", "test3"};
    vector<int> testInt = {1,2,3};
    string test = "test1";

}
```

[Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j88ve.png)

I know i can go into __r_std::1 ... to see the value of the string but im working with over 10 thousand strings that i cant verify one by one like that.

Some details, im using MacOS 13.4.1, clang 14.0.3, IDE: Clion 2022.2.5 and i tried with both c++ 20 and c++ 17.

I was expecting being able to visualize the string straight from the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

A Mac std::string has a 22-byte short string optimization limit. Here is an example of printing a short string...

```
(lldb) v inputName
(std::string) inputName = Summary Unavailable
(lldb) p inputName
(std::string) inputName = Summary Unavailable
(lldb) p inputName.c_str()
(const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::value_type *) $0 = 0x00007ff7bfef75c9 "n4"
```

Use 'p' and not 'v'. 'v' prints the frame variable but it does not have a full expression parser. 'p' is an alias for the evaluate command, which can evaluate the c_str() call and other handy things.